# Invoke the iPhones default timezone selection dialogs in an app?

Tags: iphone

Is there a way to invoke the embedded settings dialog that allows the user to select timezone?  Hate to rewrite the same thing when such a good dialog already exists.

Thanks!

Comment: We need to allow the user in our app to set the timezone for the app, which might be different from the timezone the phone is reporting, and want to be more elegant than 'Exit to the settings'